# How I can apply styling to active slide in react-image-gallery?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, styling, npm-package

I want to add custom styling to the slides and gallery control buttons in [react-image-gallery](https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery) But I am confused how to do this. I have searched the assets on google and tried to do it on my own but I am unable to apply custom styling on it.

This is the code which I have applied till now:

```html
import 'react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css';
import ImageGallery from 'react-image-gallery';

const GalleryComponent = (props)=>{

const properties = {
    thumbnailPosition: 'left',
    showFullscreenButton: false,
    useBrowserFullscreen: false,
    showPlayButton: false,
    items: [
        {
          original: "https://placeimg.com/640/480/any/1",
          thumbnail: "https://placeimg.com/250/150/any/1"
        },
        {
          original: "https://placeimg.com/640/480/any/2",
          thumbnail: "https://placeimg.com/250/150/any/2"
        },
        {
          original: "https://placeimg.com/640/480/any/3",
          thumbnail: "https://placeimg.com/250/150/any/3"
        }
      ]
  };

return (
<ImageGallery {...properties} />
)

}
```

[Currently achived this :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJDiC.png)

[Slider i wanted in actual:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5POX.png)

So kindly tell me a way to target the required components in react-image-gallery to add styling to them.
Thanks!

Comment: Hello Zohaib. Please show what you've done with your code, we cannot help you without knowing what your code is. Refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.